# Only able to make grep regex work for one line and does not continue to further lines

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Trying to grep regex from string within txt and echo a status.
.txt looks something like this:

```
something something something name1 something something Available something something something
something something something name2 something something Available something something something
something something something name3 something something Available something something something
something something something name4 something something No status something something something
something something something name5 something something No status something something something
```

I am able to find the pattern in first line and echo the status

```
cat status.txt | grep -o $name>/dev/null ; cat status.txt | grep -o "No status">/dev/null && echo $name is offline || echo $name is online
name1 is online
```

This is working correctly; but how would I go about making this work on all lines so that I would get

```
name1 is online
name2 is online
name3 is online
name4 is offline
name5 is offline
```

I have looked up and down and can not figure this out. I have also tried variations of sed and awk. nothing works. maybe I should be using python for this or something. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the point of the first grep that writes to `/dev/null`?

Comment: It was just the easiest way for me to not print the output so that i only get the echos.

Comment: If you just want the exit status of `grep` use `grep -q pattern`. And there's no point in use `-o` if you're not using the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk

```
$ awk '{if ($7 == "Available") print $4 " is online"; else print $4 " is offline"}' status.txt
name1 is online
name2 is online
name3 is online
name4 is offline
name5 is offline
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `grep` for this. Read the file line by line, extracting the information you need from it.

```
while read -r x y z name rest; do
    case "$rest" in
        *Available*) printf '%s is online\n' "$name" ;;
        *"No status"*) printf '%s is offline\n' "$name ;;
    esac
done < status.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar `awk` implementation using a *ternary* to control output based on the seventh field can be written as:

```sh
awk '{print $4 " is " ($7=="Available" ? "online" : "offline")}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file`, you would have:

```
$ awk '{print $4 " is " ($7=="Available" ? "online" : "offline")}' file
name1 is online
name2 is online
name3 is online
name4 is offline
name5 is offline
```

---

**Problems With Your Approach**

The are a number of the same inefficiencies with your approach, specifically when you do:

```sh
cat status.txt | grep -o ...; cat status.txt | grep -o ...
```

You are committing two *UUOc's* in a row. Unless you are *concatenating* two (or more) files, `cat file` is an *Unnecessary Use Of `cat`* (*UUOc*) and should be avoided. Instead just read the file or use redirection. For example:

```sh
grep -o ... status.txt; grep -o ... status.txt ...
```

Every pipe `'|'` spawns a separate subshell to tie the output of one process (`stdout`) to the input of the next (`stdin`). There is no need to `cat` to `grep`. `grep` can read the file directly or read it on `stdin` via redirection, e.g. `grep ... file` or `grep ... < file`.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Learning is "making it work". Mastering is making it work "efficiently". It all takes time. If you are new to shell utilities and scripting, time learning `awk` (and `sed`) is time well spent. `awk` is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing. `sed` is a text-stream editor. [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is a great reference. There are GNU guides for `sed` and `grep` as well. Learning isn't a race, it's more a journey, so pay attention to the details and doing things right -- the rest will come.